# ¿Cómo hacer que al pasar el mouse por cada palabra me muestre la información de otro div y no solo una img?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quiero que en lugar de que cada `div` me muestre una imagen, me muestre varios `div`. En este ejemplo que encontré no se como trabajar esta parte: var stringImg = `<img src="https://www.comenaranjas.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/manzana-royal.jpg" width="100" height="100">`; donde cada div con `id= información` me muestra una imagen, en lugar de la imagen quiero que muestre varios `div` dentro del `div` con `id=informacion`.

```js
const personajes = document.getElementsByClassName('personaje');

Array.from(personajes).forEach((elemento) => {

  elemento.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    let tarjeta = elemento.getAttribute("data-personaje");
    const img = document.getElementById("informacion");

    switch (tarjeta) {
      case "evento1":
        var stringImg = `<img src="https://www.comenaranjas.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/manzana-royal.jpg" width="100" height="100">`;
        break;
      case "evento2":
        var stringImg = `<img src="https://super.walmart.com.mx/images/product-images/img_large/00000000004024L.jpg" width="100" height="100">`;
        break;
      case "evento3":
        var stringImg = `<img src="https://arcaikastore.com/494-large_default/mora-organica-x-lb-frutas-organicas.jpg" width="100" height="100">`;
        break;
    }

    img.innerHTML = stringImg;

  });

});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#informacion {
  text-align: center;
}

#personajes {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#personajes>div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#personajes>div:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="informacion"></div>
  <div id="personajes">
    <div class="personaje" data-personaje="evento1">Evento1</div>
    <div class="personaje" data-personaje="evento2">Evento2</div>
    <div class="personaje" data-personaje="evento3">Evento3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo cambia el string de la imagen por los divs que desees que muestre :

```js
const personajes = document.getElementsByClassName('personaje');

Array.from(personajes).forEach((elemento) => {

  elemento.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    let tarjeta = elemento.getAttribute("data-personaje");
    const img = document.getElementById("informacion");

    switch (tarjeta) {
      case "evento1":
        var stringImg = `<div>este es un div<div>
                    <div>este es un otro div<div>`;
        break;
      case "evento2":
        var stringImg = `<div>este es un div2<div>
                    <div>este es un otro div2<div>`;
        break;
      case "evento3":
        var stringImg = `<div>este es un div3<div>
                    <div>este es un otro div3<div>`;
        break;
    }

    img.innerHTML = stringImg;

  });

});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#informacion {
  text-align: center;
}

#personajes {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#personajes>div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#personajes>div:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="informacion"></div>
  <div id="personajes">
    <div class="personaje" data-personaje="evento1">Evento1</div>
    <div class="personaje" data-personaje="evento2">Evento2</div>
    <div class="personaje" data-personaje="evento3">Evento3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: es decir el hecho que diga stringImg no quiere decir que solo acepte imágenes, solo es el nombre de una variable?

Comment: si exactamente ese es el nombre de la variable.. que perfectamente se puede llamar de la manera que gustes...